# XML from Excel with multiple times placed elements but different attributes

Tags: excel, xml, xsd, attributes, element

I'd like to create XML file from Excel sheet. But in my XML file there is multiple placement of same element, but always with different atributes (like element variable and atribute is that variable name).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration typical="Configurator1">
    <TypicalInstance name="Typical1">
        <Instance>
            <ConfigurationVariables>
                <ConfigurationVariable name="typical1Variable1">T1Value1</ConfigurationVariable>
                <ConfigurationVariable name="typical1Variable2">T1Value2</ConfigurationVariable>
            </ConfigurationVariables>
        </Instance>
   <Instance>
            <ConfigurationVariables>
                <ConfigurationVariable name="typical1Variable1">T1Value11</ConfigurationVariable>
                <ConfigurationVariable name="typical1Variable2">T1Value12</ConfigurationVariable>
            </ConfigurationVariables>
        </Instance>
    </TypicalInstance>
   </Configuration>
```

So I have two properties named typical1Variable1 and 2. So I need two separated columns for filling data in. Each row should be done like another Instance element.

Is this even possible with native XML mapping?

Thanks for answers.